# Iteration based is getting struck while passing values from Setup thread group to multiple main thread group

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, correlation

I am working on a scenario where i need to pass correlated value from setup thread group to multiple main thread group's which run in multiple parallel loops & also need to pass correlated values randomly in the main thread groups.

i tried property function & inter thread communication protocol plugin as well but nothing seems working for the second iteration onwards. please help on this scenario.

[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE5Eh.png)

[Correlation from set up thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY4Dz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all you need to set "Match No" to `-1` if you want to extract all `oid` instances from the response

   [image]
2. Then you need to convert them into JMeter Properties, for this add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following []][3](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('oid_matchNr') as int, index -> {
       props.put('oid_' + index, vars.get('oid_' + index))
   })

   props.put('oid_matchNr',vars.get('oid_matchNr'))
   ```
3. Then in other Thread Groups you can refer to the random match using the following [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) combination:

   ```
   ${__P(oid_${__Random(1,${__P(oid_matchNr,)},)},)}
   ```

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)